# What is best practice for SSIS in addressing data load maintaining history with missing new rows?

Tags: ssis, type-2-dimension

I'm 20 years .NET since the Beta I have SSIS since DTS and a few years serious Datawarehouse exp., dimension, fact tables etc. I've done a type2 slowly changing dimension, implementing a merge and raw SQL tasks to accomplish checking for existing rows, new rows and changed rows.

But I'm no BI developer and this isn't my forte.

I need to account for a daily data import to an ever-growing table. Mark rows (retire with a date time stamp I'm thinking) to indicate the new load didn't contain a matching row, perhaps that row has been retired? And of course the regular data load changes, new inserts updates etc. Plainly this seems like a type two slowly changing dimension.

**Is that a correct assumption based upon this limited description ?**

I am looking for time -tested accepted industry standards of how to address this scenario.

There is no data warehouse, no "dashboard" for analytic reference, this data will actually be used to support serious lookups and referenced for real billing.

I am aware of how that sounds, but the business is just trying to establish the most accurate data reference they possibly can, given the data they are getting.

Type 2 slowly changing dimension.  Odd since there is really no dimension table just a daily load of data, no analytics here at all!

I have nothing yet I am searching for a direction to implement an accepted pattern.

Generic psuedo code:

- **Row 123** (I don't even have PKs yet) comes in **and is unique** and gets loaded first to a stage table finally  to main table **in load "Monday".**
- Load **"Tuesday" Row 123** has address change and changes to let say, it's color column.... confirm row exists in both tables Update changed fields flag/update date field indicating it has changed.
- **Load "Wednesday" arrives and row 123 is not in the source data.** Retire row 123 with retire date (Special DateTime Column indicating retired also perhaps a bit flag for indicating retired )
- **Just implement a Basic Type 2?**

Comment: Yes it sounds like an SCD type 2 _without_ a surrogate key. This is a well trodden design in many applications, for example SAP. Every 'reference' row has a valid from and valid to date.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a layered SQL MERGE structure providing for the desired conditions:

WHEN MATCHED AND
(SDC Fields are changing (Different) )
     THEN UPDATE .....

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
   THEN INSERT ()

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND Target.IsRowCurrent = 1
   THEN UPDATE

This is basically just a summary from Alex Whittles' blog on purplefrogsystems.com
It seems to be the de facto standard although checking a current date instead of a "rowcurrent flag" is also very prominent.

Extra effort can be added to push all changes to a staging table and bulk load these into the desired destination table replacing Target table above with the staging table if you have a huge load of data and find that additional effort necessary.

But as is,  this is faster than the SSIS SCD row by row Wizard.

I would be remissed to not additionally mention Todd McDermid's videos of the the Kimball Method SCD component. I am not fond of tossing in someone else's pre-built component into SSIS even from the illustrious Kimball group.

I would rather understand whats is going on but if you care the video series does this walk through in two manual styles before showcasing the add in component:
 https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCks8CDxSGRRh9IbtTc3ZRqw